# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Estoy tratando de guardar una imagen en un formulario usando Forms de Django, pero cuando voy a guardar me aparece que no hay ningún archivo cargado, estoy usando el siguiente código:

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length = 45, null = True)
    categoria_id = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to = 'photos/')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class ProductoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields = ('nombre', 'precio', 'descripcion', 'categoria_id', 
            'image'
            )
        labels = { 'nombre': 'Nombre del Producto', 
                    'precio': 'Precio', 
                    'descripcion': 'Descripcion', 
                    'categoria_id' : 'Categoria',
                    'image':'imagen',
                  }
        widgets = { 'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                    'precio': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                    'descripcion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                    'categoria_id': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                    'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'name': 'image' })
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class ProductoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Producto
    form_class = ProductoForm
    template_name = 'main/add_producto.html'
    success_message = 'Success'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('funciones')
```

No tengo mucha experiencia usando `Generic Class View`, así que no se cuál es el problema de por que no me carga la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que sea porque en la `template` **add_producto.html** no tengas el `enctype="multipart/form-data"` dentro de la etiqueta form.

Si no es por esta razón, actualiza tu pregunta incluyendo el fichero **add_producto.html**.